# Native Ads Advanced (Unified) mediation click issue with facebook

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api, admob, native-ads, mobile-ad-mediation

i have successfully implemented Native Ads Advanced (Unified) in my app by following [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-unified) link but there is problem now when i turned on facebook mediation form admob everything is working fine facebook ads are loading but click listener is not working on facebook ads but it is working on google ads like click on title heading icon install button only ad showing but click listener not working on facebook native ads

Answer (score 0):

Fan-adapter is not yet released for native unified ads see my report [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/o3Tt1cshEXA)